# Volume Integral : $\int \mathrm d^3\mathbf{r}' \frac{\nabla \cdot \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r'}-\mathbf{r'}|}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, vector-analysis, electromagnetism

I am trying to understand the following claims. I would appreciate if you could help me, as I am still unable to understand it.

The problem asks us to find the following integral:
$$I = \int \mathrm d^3\mathbf{r}'\frac{\nabla \cdot \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}$$

Assuming $\mathbf{M}$ does not blow up, we can use the following identity:

$$\frac{\nabla \cdot \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|} = 
\nabla \cdot \frac{ \mathbf{M}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|} +
 \mathbf{M(r')} \cdot \nabla_{r'} \frac{ 1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}
$$

**Question 01**: It then says that if we use this expression in the integral, the first term of the sum vanishes because the **localisation** (in german **"Lokalisation"**) of **M** vanishes after using the Gauss theorem. Why should it vanish? what does localisation mean?

Then, the problem says that we are left with the following:
$$I = \nabla_{r} \int \mathrm d^3\mathbf{r}'  \frac{\mathbf{M}(\mathbf{r'})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}$$

**Question 02**: How is it that we can take the gradient out? I mean, we have a vector **M** inside, so it doesn't make any sense to me. Is this a problem of the notation used?

At the end, for a $\mathbf{M}=M_0 \mathbf{e_z}$ we get:

$$I = M_0 \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dz} \int \mathrm d^3\mathbf{r}'  \frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}|}$$

By the way, this was taken from the book: Grundkurs Theoretische Physik 3 by Wolfgang Nolting page 214

Thanks!

Comment: You can take the del out because it is with respect to the unprimed variable.

Comment: Thanks! I did not notice it at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: In my Classical Electrodynamics book (Jackson), the derivation is a little different.  By localized in Jackson, he means that there exists an object with magnetization within some fixed boundary, and $M(r) = 0$ outside (and on) that boundary.  So the first integral is $\int_V \nabla \cdot \frac{M(r')}{|r-r'|}$ dV, right?  The divergence theorem then says this integral is equal to $\int_s \frac{M(r')}{|r-r'|} \cdot n\, dS$ .  The idea then is that M(r') vanishes on this boundary.  If we want to go a little deeper, I believe you can choose the volume of integration $V$ s.t. the surface of $V$ lies outside the magnet where $M(r) = 0$.

See Classical Electrodynamics, John David Jackson.  Wiley.  This has the answer to Q2 as well.

Comment: The tricky part IMHO, that's never stated in these physics books, is that they choose an integration volume that encompasses M(r) but is slightly larger than the magnet.

Comment: Thanks! that makes complete sense. The book you gave me is also deeper and very useful.